# Why We Can't Select Data From Temporary Table into another Temporary Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Code Like

```
SELECT col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 
INTO #Temp1
FROM Emplyees;
```

and second Query :

```
SELECT Col1,Sum(Col2)
INTO #Temp2
FROM #temp1
```

The Second Query Don't Work and gave me Error as Empty or Wrong Aliases column

untill you `Select * From #Temp1 .`
This make me ASK why sql  accepted * and not for some column Selected .

Thanks For all.

Comment: do employees have the same schema, check a select * statement on #temp1 before you go for second query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Col1, Sum(Col2) as SumofCol2
INTO #Temp2
FROM #temp1
GROUP BY Col1
```

Comment: Look into using aggregate functions; should be helpful.

Comment: @Sayuri there is nothing wrong with this aggregate function

Comment: @t-clausen.dk  Well, aggregate functions often need an added GROUP BY statement. Should have conveyed it better, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Well the error is a bit misleading. I would expect it to moan about the lack of a group by clause and the lack of a real name for the second column. Try this:

```
SELECT Col1, Sum(Col2) AS SumCol
INTO #Temp2
FROM #temp1 
GROUP BY Col1
```